# WinForm C# how attach an Method to a Control programmaticaly created

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In my apps, I generated a bunch of DataGridView programmaticaly. I can add/remove rows to it and retrieve all the data from it and copy the data in another DataGrid.

for instance when Im creating it

```
public void Example(TabControl tab)
        for(int i=0;i<tab.TabCount;i++)
        {
        tab.TabPages.Add("Panneau " + tab.TabCount);
        
        DataGridView panGridView = new DataGridView();
        panGridView.Name = "panGridView_" + tab.TabCount;
        panGridView.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        panGridView.RowTemplate.Height = 24;
        panGridView.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1375, 458);
        panGridView.Columns.Add("id", "id");
        panGridView.Columns.Add("part_code", "part_code");
        panGridView.Columns[0].Width = 100;
        panGridView.Columns[1].Width = 150;
        panGridView.Visible = true;
        panIndex.Items.Add(tab.TabCount - 1);
        tab.TabPages[tab.TabCount - 1].Controls.Add(panGridView);

        }
```

Now, I want to attach Method to this Control. I think the best way would be to attach it when I initialize the Control. For example I would attach a Method like this one

```
public void Action(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
 if(e.RowIndex==2)
 {
  MessageBox.Show("Hello");
 }
```

I tried a lot of this but cant figure out how do it.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use event handler with delegate?

Comment: Can you show me how? with an Example please. Maybe this is the right way to go. Thanks

Comment: Have you ever created a button click handler? Drop a button on your form in the designer. Your form's `.cs` file will open to a click handler message. Just as importantly, you form's `.designer.cs` file will have a line added, subscribing your handler to the button's click event. Now select the button, go to the properties pane and click the Events button. You'll see your new click handler. Pick some other event. Click in the empty cell next to the name and press Enter. You'll open with a new handler. Now click you DGV and look at its events. Pick the one you're interested in and go from there

Comment: I think you need to understand the concept of event handling. [This is a good intro.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/event-handlers-overview-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) And [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/how-to-create-event-handlers-at-run-time-for-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) is exactly what you need to do

Comment: For example: TabControl.Click += ClickEvent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you want a special kind of DataGridView. You want a DataGridView with an attached method. You've learned, whenever you need a "class, very similar to another class, but with just a small thing different", you need to create a derived class, or make a composition, if you don't want to expose all methods of the base class.

```
class DataGridViewWithAttachedMethod : DataGridView   // TODO: invent proper name
{
    ...
}

class MySpecialDataGridView : UserControl
{
    private DataGridView dgv1;

    ...
}
```

The advantage of the first method is that users of your class (= code, not operators) have access to all DataGridView methods, so it will be very flexible to use. Disadvantage: they have access to all DataGridView methods, so they can mess up your DataGridView.

Whether you will use derivation or composition depends on how fool proof your class needs to be, in other words: do you want to expose methods that you prefer not to be used by others?

> I want to attach Method to this Control.

This is not really clear. Do you want to give DataGridView an extra method, always the same one? Or do you want to Dynamically attach a method: dgv1 has another attached method than dgv2.

```
class DgvWithExtraMethod : ...
{
    public void Action(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.RowIndex==2)
        {
             MessageBox.Show("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

All instances of this dgv will have the same extra method. All you have to do is create an object of this class, and you will have this method.

However, if you want to attach different methods to instances of the class, you need a property that contains this method.

```
class DgvWithMethod : ...
{
    public Action<DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs> ExtraMethod {get; set;}
}
```

If you want your class fool proof, consider to initialize the method with a "no operation (NOP)"

```
private static Action<DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs> NOP = (e) => {};

public Action<DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs> ExtraMethod {get; set;} = NOP;
```

Usage:

```
DgvWithMethod dgv1 = new DgvWithMethod
{
    ExtraMethod = (e) =>
    {
        if(e.RowIndex==2)
        {
             MessageBox.Show("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the exact answer to your question. However, what I think that you want to know is: if the operator click on row 2, then I want to execute method `F()`, and if he clicks on row 3, I want to execute method `G()`, etc

If that is what you want, use visual studio designer to add an event handler on [DataGridView.CellMouseClick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellmouseclick?view=net-5.0), or if you want to reuse this class (derivation / composition) override [DataGridView.OnCellMouseClick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.oncellmouseclick?view=net-5.0).

```
private void DataGridView1_CellMouseClick(Object sender,
    DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    // find out which column is clicked
    switch (e.ColumnIndex)
    {
        case 0: // column Id clicked
            this.ProcessColumnIdClick(e);
            break;
        case 1: // column Name clicked
            this.ProcessColumnNameClick(e);
            break;
        ...
```

Take care though: if you allow column reordering, you should compare ColumnIndex with the DisplayIndex of each column.

```
if (e.ColumnIndex == this.columnId.DisplayIndex)
    this.ProcessColumnIdClick(e);
else if (e.ColumnIndex == this.columnName.DisplayIndex)
    ...
```

Comment: Wow... and I thought that OP is looking for a simple Event subscription. Your answer is more than exact!

Comment: wonderful! IM trying that right now and give you news thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Like @CurleD stated, you simply subscribe your method to specific EventHandler. So change your Action to this:

```cs
private void panGridView_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.RowIndex==2)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    }
}
```

and then subscribe to the `CellMouseClick` event:

```cs
panGridView.CellMouseClick += panGridView_CellMouseClick;
```